# Google maps Api key error and form error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-maps

I am coding a form with location pickup and drop off. It works fine on `tryit` editor but it gives following error when it goes live.

```
Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError
```

Also the form doesn't send any information on my email when pressing submit button. The coding is as follows, can some one suggest a fix?

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeLehCRbkcg19L4j45Y4EtWESRj3uMksensor=false&libraries=places">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var input = document.getElementById('collapseOne');
            var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}};                 
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        }             
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var input = document.getElementById('collapsetwo');
            var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}};                 
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        }             
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="mailto:ezy@gmail.com" method="post" name="bform" onsubmit="return valBF();">
        <input type="hidden" name="BOOK" value="GO" /> 
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label class="placepicker form-control"></label>                <input id="collapseOne" placeholder="Pickup address" > 
                </li>
                <li> <label for="placepicker form-control"></label><input id="collapsetwo" placeholder="Dropoff address"></li>
                <li><input type="button" name="sendinfo" id="sendinfo" value="Submit" "></li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset> 
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

If there are any relevant examples please do let me know.

Comment: `the form doesn't send any information on my email when pressing submit button` - correct, because your action triggers an external application

Comment: `key=AIzaSyDeLehCRbkcg19L4j45Y4EtWESRj3uMksensor=false` - should probably be `key=AIzaSyDeLehCRbkcg19L4j45Y4EtWESRj3uMk&sensor=false` ...

Comment: It says `InvalidKeyMapError` because your key is invalid `key=AIzaSyDeLehCRbkcg19L4j45Y4EtWESRj3uMksensor=false`

Comment: I DIDNT PUT THE EXACT KEY HERE, I DELETED COUPLE OF ALPHABETS BY PURPOSE BUT IT STILLS SAME ERROR'

Comment: DO YOU KNOW ANY OTHER WAY TO SUBMIT FORM INFORMATION, ANY EXAMPLE BE APPRECIATED